# For Javascript in HTML Form Still Submits Despite Breaking Requirements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp

So essentially my problem is that I am trying to make a form where certain rules need to be met, like the password should have an uppercase and you need to confirm your password, but despite failing the validation the form will still submit. The only validation that works is the default requirement that the text box needs to have something written in it. How would I go about making it so the validation actually stops the form from going through.

The code I currently have works in that it will return true/false depending on if it passes, its just that even if it does not pass the form will still go through. I know I probably need a event.preventDefault() somehwhere but I don't know where.

```
<form  class="w3-container w3-margin" name="login" action="loginAction.jsp">
      
  <h1>Create a Username and Password</h1>
  
  <!-- These divs are the text fields for information the user needs to give the website -->
  <div class="w3-section">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="username" size="20" required>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-section">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
  </div>
  <!-- For the password the method validPassword() is used which checks if the password has an uppercase -->
  <div class="w3-section">
      <label>Password (Must have at least one upper case)</label>
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Password"  name="password" onInput="validPassword()" size="15" required>
  </div>
   <!-- For confirm password the method matchingPasswords() is used which checks if the two typed passwords are the same -->
  <div class="w3-section">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="cpassword" onInput="matchingPasswords()" size="15" required>
  </div>
  <!--These are submit and reset buttons -->
  <div class="w3-section">
    <input class="w3-button topbotColor" type="submit" value="Button" />
    <input class="w3-button topbotColor" type="reset" value="Reset" />
  </div>
      
</form>
```

This is the javascript code.

```
        //function validPassword is meant to check if the password has a uppercase letter
    function validPassword() {

      //var password stores the password element from the text box
      var password = document.getElementsByName("password");
      //var ucletters is the set of all capital letters
      var ucletters = /^(?=.*[A-Z]).+$/;

      //If there is at least one uppercase in the password text
      if(ucletters.test(password[0].value)){

        //Pass validity and return true
        document.getElementsByName("password").setCustomValidity("");
        return true;

      }
      else {

        //else the password does not have an uppercase
        document.getElementByName.setCustomValidity("This password does not fit criteria");
        return false;

      }

    }

    //matchingPasswords is meant to check if two passwords were the same
    function matchingPasswords() {

      //password stores the text in the password text box
      var password = document.getElementsByName("password");
      //cpassword stores the text in the confirm password text box
      var cpassword = document.getElementsByName("cpassword");

      //If the string in password does not match the string in confirm password
      if (password[0].value !== cpassword[0].value) {

        //it fails validity and should return false
        document.getElementsByName("cpassword").setCustomValidity("Emails do not match");
        return false;

      } 
      else {

        //else it passes and should be true
        document.getElementsByName("cpassword").setCustomValidity("");
        return true;

      }

    }

    /*function completeForm() {

      if (validPassword() !== true && matchingPasswords() !== true){

          event.preventDefault();

      }

    }*/
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Remove the forms action value

> 

2.) Add Event Listeners for your code to run(I don't see how any functions are running)

```js
document.getElementById("your_submit_button").addEventListener('click', function_you_want_to_run);
```

3.) Use this code to redirect the client to your form action

```js
window.location.url="/link.jsp";
```

Comment: You may have to do some more complicated stuff in step 3 if you want to send POST request with the form data.

Comment: Agreed with @cs641311; window.location.url will just take you there as if you typed it in the url; the form must be submitted. You can add an onSubmit listener to the form and validate it there (return true or false), or use document.forms[0].submit() or similar.